# dynamically created checkbox dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, checkbox, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically create some checkboxes based on data pulled from an API. My checkboxes are created but when I click on them they are all being checked or unchecked.
I am pretty sure I can identify why I am getting  is, I am just unsure how to overcome it.

The variable I create is for one check box, so when my list is created from ListView.builder, it is using the same variable thereby making all boxes check and uncheck. I know that I need to create that variable based on how many items are in the list. I am just not sure how to do this and where within my code structure. I tried different methods of using .length or trying to use a .forEach but none of it was correct in the method I was implementing it. I have included my code that shows how I am creating my list of tags.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/backend/api/api_services.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/models/tag_list_model.dart';

class TagsListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int companyId;
  const TagsListWidget({Key? key, required this.companyId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TagsListWidget> createState() => _TagsListWidgetState(companyId);
}

class _TagsListWidgetState extends State<TagsListWidget> {
  final int companyId;
  late bool checkboxListTileValue = false;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  _TagsListWidgetState(this.companyId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Tags",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).title2.override(
              fontFamily: 'Heebo',
              fontSize: 18.sp,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
            iconSize: 40,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 20,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Test");
            },
          )
        ],
        leading: IconButton(
          hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconSize: 40,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_return_sharp,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: ApiService().getTagList(companyId),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Tags tags = snapshot.data[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (() {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        }),
                        child: Center(
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            value: checkboxListTileValue,
                            onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() {
                              checkboxListTileValue = newValue!;
                            }),
                            title: Text(tags.tag,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                    .title3
                                    .override(
                                        fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18.sp)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create List:

```
List<bool> checkboxValue = [];
```

then use it like this:

```
return StatefulBuilder(// add this
            builder: (c, innerSetState) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (() {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                }),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Tags tags = snapshot.data[index];
                      checkboxValue = List<bool>.generate(snapshot.data.length,(counter) => false); // add this
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (() {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        }),
                        child: Center(
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            value: checkboxValue[index], //add this
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                               innerSetState(() {// add this
                                  checkboxValue[index] = newValue;
                               });
                            },
                            title: Text(tags.tag,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                    .title3
                                    .override(
                                        fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18.sp)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            },
          );
```

note that this work when checkbox value not come from api, if it is let me know so I can Update my answer.

Comment: The argument type 'List<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool?'. This is the error I get when trying to use this solution.

Comment: I run this code but get no error.

Comment: I was forgetting the [index] on the value: This got rid of my error, however I now do not see any box check/uncheck. It just runs the api call over and over as I can see it print the data in the terminal

Comment: call the api over and over may address to an other thing and it is not because of answer.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the time/effort you are using to help me. I have matched my code to your solution and the boxes are not able to be marked/unmarked. They remain empty.  What could be causing this?

Comment: i update my answer and add comment line to specify changes to you. please check you are adding all three of theme

Comment: I indeed have all the changes you show. to reinforce that, lets move this conversation to a chat so I can show you my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247390/discussion-between-mackina-and-eamirho3ein).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, that you use varieble checkboxListTileValue in global scope. Then yo set new value in:

```
onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() {
                              checkboxListTileValue = newValue!;})
```

Global checkboxListTileValue applayed to all ListView items.
You can made the List checkboxListTileValue, with defaul value set. And onChage set the new value only for item with index which was clicked.

```
onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() {
                              checkboxListTileValue[index] = newValue!;})
```

Comment: The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'bool'.
Try defining the operator '[]='.  This is the error I get when I try to use [index] after checkboxListTileValue

Comment: Yes, you need to define List<bool> with the name of checkboxListTileValue.

Comment: I do have List<bool> defined as checkBoxListTileValue.  I changed my code to List<bool> checkBoxListTitleValue = []; 
The error I am getting now is:

The argument type 'List<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool?'

Answer (score 0):

You are using single `bool` to control the checked status of a list. You can create a model class with a bool filed that will be like `bool isCheked=false` , Once you click on item check it is already checked or not and change the value.
Or create a List that will hold `tags.tag` value.

```dart
List<String> selected = [];

....
 value: selected.contains(tags.tag),
onChanged: (newValue)  
  { 
   if(selected.contains(tags.tag)){
    selected.remove(tags.tag); }
   else{
      selected.add(tags.tag); 
  }
setState((){});
```

Comment: This works, allowing me to check/uncheck the first box in a series of 3, however when I check/uncheck boxes 2 or 3, they check/uncheck at the same time.

Comment: Mostly like they are having same tag, store something that is unique

Comment: its all dummy data, so some of the values will be the same. How can I account for that?